# Nusach of my family

Tags: minhag

Mordka Moszek Worcman (my great-great-grandfather of my direct patrilineal ancestry) was born in 1849 in Ostrowiec Świętokrzyski, and there were synagogues that followed the Minhag Polin (Misnagdim) and synagogues that followed the Nusach Sefard (Hasidim of Ger, Aleksander, Vorka and Shidlovtza). The son of Mordka Moszek Worcman and my great-great-grandfather, Szymon Majer Worcman, married in 1896 in Łódź, where there were synagogues of Minhag Polin (Misnagdim) and Nusach Sefard (Hasidim of Ger and Aleksander). The grandson of Szymon Majer Worcman and my grandfather, Szymon Meir Worcman, was born in 1928 in Łódź and immigrated to Rio de Janeiro in 1939, where my family lives today. It turns out that in Rio de Janeiro there are synagogues that follow Minhag Polin, Minhag Ashkenaz, Minhag Aram Soba, Minhag Morocco, Minhag Edot HaMizrach and Nusach Ari (Hasidim from Chabad Lubavitch). Should my family follow Minhag Polin or Nusach Sefard if I don't know if Mordka Moszek Worcman was Hasidic or not?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya @Zeca - this is a question for a Rabbi. Hatzlocho (best of luck) with your search!

Comment: If you go back a few more generations (say to 1750) and assume your forebears were still living in Eastern Europe , they were almost certainly praying with Minhag Polin

Comment: There's a very important Igros Moshe on this. I've simplified the question here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138133/if-someones-ancestry-was-a-mix-of-hassidic-and-non-hassidic-ashkenazi-what-nus

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?